# GET Values and send to next page based on Selected in Dropdown

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a drop down menu and based on what is selected I want to post to URL from Page 1 and then pass to Page 2(using GET).

Initially I did this but instead of a drop down I had a long list of data from database and clicked each 1 of my list which works perfectly and passed through to page 2. However I don't want a long list on the page, I just want to select from drop down which I currently have but I can not pass multiple criteria as per my URL below:

> localhost/website/page?col1=3645&col2=183&col3=845

When I select and Submit its only posting to URL the name of the drop down along with the value. Which looks like this

> localhost/website/page?col1=3645

But I want it like this

> localhost/website/page?col1=3645&col2=183&col3=845

I can not put multiple names="" for the dropdown for example.

I hope I make sense here

Also Tried messing with entering the required

```
<?php echo $col1; ?> <?php echo $col2; ?><?php echo $col3; ?>
```

inside the value="" of the drop down , but then it just clumps it altogether like this

> localhost/website/page?col1=3645183845SELECT=Submit
>   in the URL, Which means I can not GET individual values as it sees as 1 value  and not 3 separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code ,

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="">---SELECT---</option>
    <option value="page2.php?id=1&val=1&key=1">Option with value1</option>
    <option value="page2.php?id=2&val=2&key=2">Option2 with value2</option>
</select>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('#mySelect').change(function(){ 
    var value =$(this).val();
    if(value!=''){
        window.location=value;
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which is your situation (I don't see the HTML code you are using), you could address the issue in several ways:

- I would use hidden inputs where I will save the data you want to send to the second page, and when you click in the submit button they will be sent as well
- Or, if you already have other form elements, like dropdowns or inputs, just group them all under the same form tag, and they will be sent all together whe you click in the submit button
- If you want the request to be fired WHEN the user selects an option from the dropdown, then you could gather the form data (inputs and selects) using JavaScript, and send it all using an AJAX call

Comment: Thanks Jobz and Carlos Alberto Martínez Gadea for both your responses. I really appreciate it. Jobz -> your code worked perfectly and was exactly as I needed it! - Thanks again